# "no J3D in java.library.path" in Maven Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-3d, unsatisfiedlinkerror

The error I'm getting is well discussed here, but I still can't seem to get a grip on what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to run a simple code with java3d. I added the jard to the Maven Dependencies and they are showing up. No errors are displayed and everything seems fine.

But when I'm trying to compile the code, all of a sudden the message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl$22.run(MasterControl.java:889)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:886)
at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:229)
at de.act.gui.Skelett3D.main(Skelett3D.java:15)
```

appears.

Apparently I'm just missing some trivial error. Since the question has been asked so many times, the answer should be somewhere.

I added the Jars via the pom.xml with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>java3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>j3d-core-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a native library (i.e. a `dll` or `so` file).

I do not know how to correctly reference that from maven (apparently there is something like a NAR that you can built, but I have not researched that yet).

A quick solution for eclipse is to add the dll as a native dependency to your `Maven Dependencies` library in eclipse:

In the "Libraries" tab in "Java Build Path" in the project properties, expand "Maven Dependencies" and edit "Native library location" to point to the directory containing your native library.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution is not working try to manually install maven and j3d, or reinstall it.
a missing file is sometimes a really bad sign, because sometimes if 1 file is missing maybe you haven't installed propertly and other files will be missing later on so i suggest you reinstalling.